# Modifying LexisNexisTools in R (RStudio) to rename files

Tags: r

I'm trying to rename .txt files in a directory downloaded from Nexis Advance UK. Being unfamiliar with coding, I set about trying to modify [LexisNexisTools'](https://github.com/JBGruber/LexisNexisTools) code in RStudio.

What I've done is change `term.v <- content_v[grep("^Terms: |^Begriffe: ", content_v)]` to `term.v <- content_v[grep("The Guardian(London)", fixed = T, content_v)]`, for instance, and changed the rename function so that it only pastes `term.v`. However, I'm trying to retain the original `OR` function so that the code would cycle through a number of strings such "Express Online" or "The Independent (United Kingdom)" and then paste the string found into the file rename function.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1 - Use regular expressions (from what I could gather online on regular expressions with spaces in strings) with `fixed = F`, such as `"^The/sGuardian(London)$|^Express/sOnline$"`

2- I've tried using a vector to "house" the different patterns and then paste the vector in the grep command

```
toMatch.v <- c("Express Online", "The Times (London)", "The Independent (United Kingdom)" 

term.v<- content_v[grep(paste(toMatch, collapse="|"),  content_v)]
```

The only time the code (as modified) works is when `fixed = T` and the string is typed as is found in the .txt files.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much and I apologize if the terminology isn't accurate.

## Extra details:

Originally, the code relies on a set of keywords to find the search term and insert it into the file's name:

```
    content_v <- readLines(files[i], encoding = encoding, n = 50)
    term.v <- content_v[grep("^Terms: |^Begriffe: ", content_v)]
    # erase everything in the line exept the actual range
    term.v <- gsub("^Terms: |^Begriffe: ", "", term.v)
    # split term into elemets seprated by and or OR
    term.v <- unlist(strsplit(term.v, split = " AND | and | OR ", fixed = FALSE))
```

I have changed it so that `grep` begins with the string that I want to append to the filename, as explained above. I have also disabled the `gsub` line and changed the `split` argument to `"/n"` as the string in my text files is separated with line breaks. [Here is an example of a sample .txt file.](https://textuploader.com/1q1wb)

Comment: To me, it's unclear what you're asking. From your first paragraph, I thought that you want to work with filenames (e.g., change the name of a file on, e.g., your hard drive, from `file1.txt` to `file2.txt`). This could potentially be done with functions like `file.rename()`. But then, in the rest of your question, you deal with object in memory. Could you give a few examples of what objects/filenames you have and also of the desired output?

Comment: Thank you, hplieninger! I apologize if the question seemed unclear. The main function I’m after is file-name renaming, and I’m using this code to rename the .txt files on my hard-drive based on whether each file has the string defined in the grep function.

Comment: For instance, let’s say that I have two .txt files, “test1” and “test2”. I want for the code to see if each of the files has the string “The Guardian” or “Express Online” and then, if this condition is met, to have whichever string found replace the file-name.

Comment: For your example file, what would the new file name look like? Just `"Express Online.txt"`?

Comment: Yes. It would appear as “ExpressOnline.txt” however only if fixed = T in the grep function and the string is set exactly as it appears in the file, i.e., term.v <- content_v[grep("Express Online", content_ v)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly your file format is quite different from how the files looked when I wrote `LexisNexisTools`. And so are your requirements. So I would write new code to do the job here. First, let's try for one file:

```
f <- "/home/johannes/Documents/x.txt"
lines <- readLines(f)

toMatch.v <- c("Express Online", "The Times (London)", "The Independent (United Kingdom)")

# I'm using another function from the package to convenietly look up a several patterns at once
np <- unlist(LexisNexisTools::lnt_lookup(lines, toMatch.v, verbose = FALSE))[1]
new_name <- paste0(dirname(f), "/", np, ".txt")
new_name
#> [1] "/home/johannes/Documents/Express Online.txt"

file.rename(f, new_name)
```

Once this works for you as intended, you can implement it for a number of files. As in my original function I would suggest you write your new names in a data.frame first so you can check if the new names make sense and if you have duplicates in the new names (`R` would write both files into the new name without warning and destroy one file in that case):

```
files <- list.files("/home/johannes/Documents/", pattern = ".txt$", 
                    ignore.case = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

make_new_name <- function(old_name) {
  lines <- readLines(old_name)

  np <- unlist(LexisNexisTools::lnt_lookup(lines, toMatch.v, verbose = FALSE))[1]
  paste0(dirname(old_name), "/", np, ".txt")
}  

df <- tibble::tibble(
  old = files,
  new = sapply(files, make_new_name)
)
df               
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   old                              new                                        
#>   <chr>                            <chr>                                      
#> 1 /home/johannes/Documents//x.txt  /home/johannes/Documents/Express Online.txt
#> 2 /home/johannes/Documents//x2.txt /home/johannes/Documents/Express Online.txt
```

If the new names make sense to you and if there are no duplicates (`table(duplicated(df$new))`), you can pull the trigger and rename the files:

```
file.rename(df$old, df$new)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, JBGruber! You have been a great help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a file `file1.txt` with something like the following content in your working directory:

```
foo
foo bar Express Online
bar
```

Then, the following code should rename the file into `Express Online.txt`.

```r
file1 <- "file1.txt"

text1 <- readLines(file(file1))

# if (any(grepl("The Guardian", text1))) {
#     file.rename(file1, "The Guardian.txt")
# } else if (any(grepl("Express Online", text1))) {
#     file.rename(file1, "Express Online.txt")
# }

newname <- head(
    n = 1,
    na.omit(
        stringr::str_extract(
            text1,
            "(Express Online)|(The Times \\(London\\))|(The Independent \\(United Kingdom\\))")))

file.rename(file1, paste0(newname, ".txt"))
```

Comment: Thank you, hplieninger! I’ll try to work that in the code.

Comment: The version with `str_extract()` is probably more convenient than the `if`s if you have many different elements you are searching for. Note that in your linked sample file, both the pattern `Express Online` and `The Guardian` appear. I take the first of them using `head()`, but this might need to be adapted.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help and efforts!